# Kafka error - 'Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I have a Kafka docker set up that I was able to run properly with the following docker-compose.yml.

```
> version: '2'
> 
> services:
>     zookeeper:
>         image: bitnami/zookeeper:3.8
>         ports:
>             - 2181:2181
>         environment:
>             - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
>             #- ZOO_ENABLE_AUTH=yes
>     kafka:
>         image: bitnami/kafka:2.5.0
>         ports:
>             - 9092:9092
>             - 9091:9091
>         links:
>             - zookeeper
>         environment:
>             - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=true
>             - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
>             - KAFKA_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:9091,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
>             - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=EXTERNAL://localhost:9092,INTERNAL://kafka:9091
>             - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
>             - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
```

I am trying to connect using conflient-kafka and my producer code looks as below

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import socket

conf = {'bootstrap.servers': "127.0.0.1:9092",
        "enable.ssl.certificate.verification": False,
        'client.id': socket.gethostname()}

producer = Producer(conf)
producer.produce('my_topic', key="key", value="value")
producer.flush()
```

I am having the following error when I run it

> Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect
> security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or
> broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 2ms in state
> APIVERSION_QUERY)

I noticed the following

- Kafka broker version is 2.5.
- docker-compose log shows
  ssl.client.auth = none
  ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Putting localhost in `KAFKA_LISTENERS` stops remote connections from being made. Use `EXTERNAL://:9092` or put 0.0.0.0, not localhost. Only put localhost in the advertised listeners. You might also want to use a newer version of the container (versions 3.4+ don't need Zookeeper). You can also remove the forwarded 9091 port since that's not doing anything

Comment: I am reasonably new to installing Kafka and I misguidedly ended up following some instructions from the internet. As @OneCricketeer mentioned,  kafka does not require zookeeper anymore. Follow this link `https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/` to install kafka. I also had some problem resolving the hostname from my python kakfka producer. Depends on your OS, an ifconfig command get you host ip address. Everything was up and running after that :)

Comment: You don't need to use your host ip. The bitnami container docs explain how to setup external or internal docker clients